# Stack Overflow profile account GUI bug in Google Chrome

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, profile-page, user-accounts

### Problem

I had a problem with one bug in my Stack Overflow account user profile while I wanted to click on next badge.

[image]

### Solution

Through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> console I selected item boxes and deleted that panel which was before that blue one and after that I could lick on "Let us pick".

### Versions/settings

- I use Acer Aspire with Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit - all up-to-date
- I opened Stack Overflow on extended monitor DELL(1280x1024) with correctly working VGA connector
- Google Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- in Chrome I have only these extensions installed:

  - AdBlock
  - Scopus Document Download Manager
  - Google Scholar

Why did this GUI mistake happen? Is it a problem on my site or server site? Can I do something to not repeat it again?